# "There exists a" does it mean At least one or Exactly one...

Tags: logic, graph-theory

There exists a minimum weight edge in G which is present in every minimum spanning tree of G.

Does it mean, We only have one minimum weight edge in G and that minimum weight edge should be in every Minimum Spanning Tree of G.

Or does it mean, We have at least one minimum weight edge in every minimum spanning tree of G?

I understand that Grammatically, 'Exists' is singular.
But, some more clarifications would really be helpful.

Comment: The mathematical meaning is "there is at least one"

Comment: Sir, how would 'Minimum' and 'Minimal' affect and say different things here, Can you elaborate?

Comment: Sir, There is at least one minimum weight edge in G which is present in every Minimum Spanning Tree of G. Sir, are we being specific about particular minimum weight edge or Are we just meaning that, at least one minimum weight edge is present in every minimum spanning tree of G.

Comment: "Only one" is "exactly one".

Comment: I think the wording of the claim in the OP could be stated more clearly. I think it means "there exists at least one minimal weight edge $x$ in $G$ such that $x$ is present in every Minimal Spanning Tree of $G$."

Comment: @Ned, Sir, This was the statement given to me and I had to specify 'true' or 'false'. Of course I'm aware that multiple minimum spanning trees might exists when we have more than one minimum weight. I'm still not getting the difference it would create on writing "minimal". Can you please elaborate? Or is it just not right choice of word?

Comment: I thought perhaps your question was about "uniformity" in the statement-- I don't know anything about graphs (i.e. the content of the question). My comment was that the statement seems to assert that the graph contains a minimal edge $x$ that lies in every MST of G, which is stronger than saying "every MST of G contains a minimal edge." The statement allows that there may be more than one such minimal edge $x$ (the question of "uniqueness") in G, but it says the desired edge $x$ must be in every MST.

Answer (score 1):

"There exists" ($\exists$) means at least one; for uniqueness, we use $\exists!$.

Comment: Sir, thanks for specifying uniqueness symbol which I wasn't aware of. Can you tell me, just to clarify my thoughts, Are "There exists a", "There exist" (note: 's' is not written) are both same as "At least one" i.e. "There exists" mathematically?

Comment: @sgoel It's always "at least one", unless specified otherwise.

Comment: Sir, Is it okay to say that There are some set of different English Sentences(having a different meaning) which mean exactly same Mathematically?